# Java $APP_PACKAGE Pathname Variable Not Working

Tags: java, macos, info.plist

According to the [Java Info.plist Key Reference for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001969), you're supposed to be able to use the $APP_PACKAGE variable to be able to access the root directory of a Mac Application bundle. So I figure that I can store a file in the Contents/Resources/ folder and access it by calling

```
new File("$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Resources/MyFile.txt")
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I simply get a file not found error. Moreover, I've tried the following to see if I could narrow down the problem:

```
new File("$APP_PACKAGE/Contents").exists() //Returns false
System.out.printline(new File("$APP_PACKAGE").getParent()) //Returns an empty string
```

I did generate the Mac OS X bundle using Eclipse's Export to Mac OS X application bundle, if that matters. Any help (or a suitable workaround) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Even though the app had a hard time telling me what the working directory is, I managed to figure out that it is the folder that the application is in. Then I was able to solve it by referring to the app as a directory:

```
new File("MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyFile.txt").exists() //Returns true!!!
```

I'd also like to add that I found the suggestion on [this blog post](http://howlingmoonsoftware.com/wordpress/?p=36) to add the following to my info.plist file:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Resources</string>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work on Mac OS 10.7.5 and the working directory just gets reset to the folder that the application is in.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is set as as an environment variable, you may use `System.getEnv()` to first get the actual value of `APP_PACKAGE` then create the `File` object using it.

```
String appPackage = System.getEnv("APP_PACKAGE");
new File(appPackage + "/Contents/Resources/MyFile.txt");
```

That said, from the reading of your [given link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001969) I wonder if this variable is just expended while read from the `plist` file, not in your Java process. If the variable is not actually given as an environment variable to your Java program, you can retrieve your file in the `Contents` directory easily since as I remember the packaging of an app on Mac should have the following architecture

```
/Contents
  /MacOS
    YourBinary
  /Resources
    YourFile.txt
```

Depending on the current working directory of your app (I think it should default to `/Contents/MacOS`) you can retrieve the correct path using `../Resources/YourFile.txt`. If you don't know the current working directory you can print the value of `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: System.getenv("APP_PACKAGE") is returning an empty string for me.

Comment: You're correct about the structure of a Mac OS X bundle (with a Java folder inside the Resources folder holding all the JAR files needed). Unfortunately, ../Resources/YourFile.txt isn't working and new File(".").getAbsolutePath() results in a NullPointerException. Same with getPath().